# Loading ObservableCollection with datetime values from an array

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, windows-8

I have a ListView in a Class called HistoryStatistics and its template looks like this. Every item will have a button and two textblocks.

```
    <ListView x:Name="HistoryLV" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="historyDatesTBlock" Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Coral"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="cycleLengthTBlock" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Now I need to data bind the textboxes with two different values. I have a class called CycleManager. It has an DateTime Array. I want to databind first n values of array to the first textblock.

In the constructor of HistoryStatistics I have a function called LoadListView.

```
    public void LoadListView()
    {
        CycleManager cycMan = CycleManager.Instance;            
        DateTime[] items = cycMan.GetHistoryArray();
        HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>(items);
        HistoryLV.DataContext = HistoryList;
    }
```

Is this the correct way of binding DateTime? I tried adding ToString yet not dates are being displayed.

Is there a way by which you can create a ListView in code behind and bind individual items with the values I want by running through a forloop?

Comment: You may need to add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in `HistoryLV`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding the following line to your LoadListView method. I have not tried this myself as I don't have Windows 8 setup on my system.

```
HistoryLV.ItemsSource = HistoryList;
```

Comment: Im developing for Windows 8

Comment: oh ya :) , still you can try setting the datasource

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CycleManager cycMan = CycleManager.Instance;            
DateTime[] items = cycMan.GetHistoryArray();

string[] list = new string[items.Length];
for(int i=0; i<items.Length; i++)
{
    list[i] = items[i].ToString("**The DateTime format you want**");
}

HistoryList = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);
HistoryLV.ItemsSource = HistoryList;
```